# Solving detailed combustion kinetics in CFD, where to start?

Tags: ode, numerical-modelling, stiffness

I have some experience solving single- and multicomponent Euler equations for modeling of gas flows, including combustible ones. The code (variations of finite-difference WENO methods) is written with C language.

Till now, I've implemented only simple combustion models such as 1-stage propane combustion (Westbrook-Dryer) and 2-stage hydroden combustion (Korobeinikov-Levin). Now I'd like to move to more complex kinetics that involve, for example, 9 components with 19 reactions, such as [O'Conaire](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/kin.20036?casa_token=n1jDGRTwwSoAAAAA%3A9JNtpAg8zvjXjIQvp9f4D0SnFJLXYRXpMaEolIQbbZi99qFMRJgdcSUlWDLM0FPrYV7UlAG5HR7BmDfYUA) model. As far as I understand, corresponding ODE systems are typically quite stiff.

After preliminary research I got somewhat overwhelmed by the multitude of methods and papers available on the topic. What would be the good starting point to develop solver code for such kinetics? Maybe a particular textbook, some basic papers or some code library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the closest thing to a "definitive" ODE solvers book is Hairer's [Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1) and [Solving Ordinary Differential Equations II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-05221-7). The first book covers non-stiff problems and the second one covers stiff problems, though it might be a little difficult to understand some of the material in II without I.

These books focus on the fundamental theory of why methods like Runge-Kutta work and how to derive your own methods and go about proving their stability/accuracy properties. They are a bit dense if all you are looking for are methods that others have developed and found to work well, though they will help you understand the terminology the papers use such as when they say a method is "A-stable" or "L-stable".

[Finite Difference Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898717839) by LeVeque is another good introductory book and goes into some of the details of actually implementing these methods in code to solve problems.

If you're looking for existing implementations of methods which many people tend to use in practice, the two I'm most familiar with are [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) in SciPy and [SUNDIALS](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials) for C/C++, though there are lots of options.
These are what most usually use for practical codes because they're well tested and verified to work, but the fundamental theory gives you an understanding of what the various options do in these libraries (ex. when would I use Radau vs. BDF vs. DOP853 in solve_ivp?)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the answer I was hoping for. How could I not think of LeVeque, knowing of his excellent books on FV methods and method for conservation laws :-)

Comment: One comment for future viewers: when compiling SUNDIALS under windows, one may encounter unexpected problems with linking errors. In my case, compiling only static libraries (without shared ones) worked, similar to situation mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sundials-users/c/trfv_kLOtu4/m/kQmTD2-rBQAJ).

Answer (score 1):

For *codes*, the AMReX suite is very powerful. The combustion line that deals with chemical kinetics is called [Pele](https://amrex-combustion.github.io/), which to my understanding is well respected.

For *books*, consider Forman Williams' books like [this one](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/6077037) and [Ken Kuo's book](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/5829156).

Some of the work in kinetics area is done by folks like [Hai Wang](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehaiwang), [Joe Oefelein](https://ae.gatech.edu/people/joseph-oefelein), [Guillaume Blanquart](https://www.theforce.caltech.edu/), [Heinz Pitsch](https://www.itv.rwth-aachen.de/en/institute/staff-contact/prof-dr-ing-heinz-pitsch-institutsleiter/), [Forman Williams](http://maeresearch.ucsd.edu/williams/), and many, many others.

**Note:** These lists are far from exhaustive. This is a large research area with many people doing impressive things. When wading into new waters, it is good practice to pick up a well-known book and a Ph.D. thesis or two (pay close attention to the introductions!) on the topic you are interested in.